# LUIS return DatetimeV2 entities but my app is receiving just datetime entities

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

If a enter a query directly to LUIS in my browser it will return the correct DatetimeV2 entity:

```
 "entities": [
{
  "entity": "after 2010",
  "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.daterange",
  "startIndex": 43,
  "endIndex": 52,
  "resolution": {
    "values": [
      {
        "timex": "2010",
        "Mod": "after",
        "type": "daterange",
        "start": "2010-12-31"
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

When I submit the same query in my app, the RecognizerResult only returns:

```
"datetime": [
{
  "type": "daterange",
  "timex": [
    "2010"
  ]
}]
```

I am using Microsoft Bot Builder 4.0.1 and the built in Luis recognizer middleware . This is how I am accessing the RecognizerResult

```
  public static RecognizerResult GetRecognizerResult(ITurnContext context)
    {
        return context.Services.Get<RecognizerResult>
                (LuisRecognizerMiddleware.LuisRecognizerResultKey);
    }
```

Comment: could you provide the JSON model of your LUIS app so we could try to repro? Also what utterance are you using to test? You can check out the docs here if you don't know how to export the file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-manage-versions#export-version

Comment: I do a test with my luis app and bot application, which work as expected. Please share the details of entities that you created so that we can reproduce the issue. Besides, you can use Fiddler to capture the request of luis service sent from your bot application and check the response, if possible, please share the response details too.